# Why are subsites' MathJax delimiters different?

Tags: discussion, markdown, mathjax

Why are subsites' MathJax delimiters different?

On sites like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) they are `\$...\$`.

On sites like [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/482283/firstlove) they are `$...$`

Why don't let them have the same schema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in some sites, MathJax was enabled later on after a request by the community, and dollar signs were already used in posts. 'Blindly' activating MathJax would break the formatting on those posts, hence the `\$` delimiters. An example can be found [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/mathjax-on-codereview#comment4768_1708):

> MathJax is currently enabled with `$ … $` as delimiters. However, that breaks existing posts that contain two dollar signs within the same paragraph, but where the code is not formatted using backticks or a code block. We would like to change it to use `\$ … \$` as delimiters, as on [Electrical Engineering](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/434/27394).