# Include variable names and formula in LaTeX style

Tags: discussion, mathjax, latex

I have some lengthy discussions and detailed questions in other threads and need to include formulas or just variable names which are not clearly readable in plain text.

Example: `V_CE` should look like $V_{CE}$ in [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) style.

I have seen this formatting in questions and even comments, but I am not able to find the correct way to implement it into my own contributions.

Comment: Are you just looking for a guide on how to use mathjax formatting in your posts? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Note only a some sites support this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank yout

Comment: See also: ["Why are subsites' MathJax delimiters different?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308715/282094), ["What **site-specific post formatting** settings are available?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298843/282094), [OR.SE MathJax FAQ](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/51), ["Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/282094).

Comment: Stack Exchange site *Mathematics* has the awesome *[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)*.

Comment: Does this behavior is different for different exchanges? The inline formulas do not work for me (e.g. $V_{CE}$ makes a new line). See comment https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478263/power-dissipation-bjt-transistor-as-voltage-follower

Comment: @v3xX See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax , as Mark Kirby and Rob already suggested. It tells you how to use MathJax on Electrical Engineering.