# What delimiters work for MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I thought I knew a thing or two about post formatting, but these posts on the two Mathematics sites surprised me: [Vector Convolution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4372833/228959) (Mathematics SE) and [Vector convolution?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/415275/70594) (MathOverflow). The first equation in those posts uses MathJax but without the familiar `$` or `$$` ([or on selected sites, `\$`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308715/295232)) delimiters; instead MathJax seems to detect `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` now. [This very old post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100972/295232) seems to suggest that didn't work before, but I assume that was an old version of MathJax. Is this behaviour documented somewhere, and are there more delimiters like this?

Comment: This may not be a canonical list but [this Math Meta post _MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference_](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/512954) (which is linked from [this CR meta qustion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3909/120114)) mentions those delimiters (between the question and various answers)

Comment: The delimiter `\begin{equation}` worked as far back as at least [2018 (kinda)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310419/323179).

Comment: Perhaps relevant: from the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/delimiters.html#tex-delimiters), "By default, MathJax will also render all environments outside of delimiters, e.g., `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}` would be processed even if it is not in math mode delimiters…"

Comment: Thanks for the references. It might be that `\begin{(\w+)}` and `\end{(\w+)}` works (as long as both groups are equal), or only certain keywords?

Comment: If I had more time ..., I think this is going to be the answer, so this is what you need to search for: https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/issues/712#issuecomment-304531595 and in particular:  https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/blob/main/contrib/auto-render/index.html

Comment: @Rob KaTex is a software independent of MathJax. It can and does have different behaviour, so it is not relevant for this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the delimiters that I confirmed to work on MathOverflow (it will be a bit different on sites that use [`\$`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308715) instead of `$`). I’m not sure if the list is comprehensive; feel free to fix it if anything is missing or inaccurate:

- **Inline math** delimiters `$ ... $`.

  <sub><sup>(Neither `\( ... \)` nor `\\( ... \\)` work.)</sup></sub>
- **Display math** delimiters `$$ ... $$` and `\\[ ... \\]`.

  <sub><sup>(The latter is an escaped version of LaTeX’s `\[ ... \]`.)</sup></sub>
- **LaTeX-style environments** `\begin{<name>} ... \end{<name>}`.

  Here, `<name>` is any string with balanced braces `{ ... }`; it must be the same in `\begin` and in `\end`, otherwise it is not recognized as a delimiter. <sub><sup>(Improperly nested environments such as `\begin{equation} ... \begin{align} ... \end{equation}` *are* recognized as MathJax delimiters, but lead to MathJax error messages.)</sup></sub>

  MathJax predefines common equation environments such as `equation`, `align`, or `matrix`; moreover, it supports user-defined environments using the `\newenvironment` command. The `\begin{<name>} ... \end{<name>}` structure is in any case recognized as a MathJax delimiter even if environment `<name>` does not exist, or if it is invalid as an environment name (e.g., if it includes unexpandable control sequences), however such cases lead to MathJax error messages.

  <sub><sup>For single-letter environment names, `\begin X` and `\end X` are *not* recognized as MathJax delimiters, even though they work fine *inside* already-recognized MathJax expressions (just like in actual LaTeX).</sup></sub>

  <sub><sup>Unlike LaTeX, MathJax allows equation environments to be enclosed in other delimiters, such as `$$\begin{align} ... \end{align}$$`. The outer delimiters are redundant.</sup></sub>

  <sub><sup>Fun fact: both MathJax and LaTeX allow defining an environment with *empty name* with `\newenvironment{}{X}{Y}`. This redefines the `\end` command, wreaking havoc left and right; it appears that in LaTeX, `\newenvironment{<name>}` only checks for the existence of `\<name>`, but not for `\end<name>`, and happily redefines it if it exists. Sounds like a bug, if you ask me.</sup></sub>

Comment: In LaTeX you can't do `\newcommand{\end...}`, so there's no need to check whether `\end<name>` exists in `\newenvironment{<name>}` as environments in their command form are always paired up. You don't, for example, have `\something` end with `\endsomethingelse` under `\newenvironment{something}`. It's *always* `\something`...`\endsomething`. Of course, in TeX you can do that.

Comment: @Werner The point is that `\end` *already exists* in LaTeX, it does not need to be defined with `\newcommand`. And then, as I wrote in the answer, LaTeX accepts `\newenvironment{}{...}{...}` and erroneously overwrites `\end`, which completely breaks further environments.

Comment: There is absolutely no value in doing `\newenvironment{}{X}{Y}`. You can also do `\renewenvironment{document}{X}{Y}` and screw things up equally. Some basic/fundamental understanding of a language is required when using (re)definitions.

Comment: I don’t see much value in continuing this increasingly off-topic discussion, but anyway: you are making a strawman argument. A `\renewenvironment` is explicitly saying “I’m redefining an existing environment. I know what I’m doing. And even if I don’t, it’s my fault if this breaks anything.” In contrast, a `\newenvironment` *pretends* to check that the environment is safe to define, and does not conflict with any preexisting macros. It turns out that the check is half-hearted, and may fail to detect some conflicts; that’s a bug.